# How to create a form add-in at the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, custom-fields

Currently creating a site for a client during my internship end of study.
I am looking to create a button that will allow to add existing sections of my form.

I try to add it thanks to a function in Javascript however when I click on the button nothing happens, however when I do a console.log ('test') in the console hello

```
function dog_func ($atts) {
    $list=array(

    'Affenpinscher' => 'Affenpinscher',
    'Airedale Terrier' => 'Airedale Terrier',
    'Ariégeois' => 'Ariégeois',
    'Barbet' => 'Barbet',
    'Barbu Tchèque' => 'Barbu Tchèque' ,
    'Berger de Russie' => 'Berger de Russie',  
    'Berger des Pyrénées' => 'Berger des Pyrénées',
    'Berger des Shetland' => 'Berger des Shetland',
    'Berger du Caucase' => 'Berger du Caucase',
    'Berger du massif du Karst' => 'Berger du massif du Karst',
    'Berger finnois de Laponie' => 'Berger finnois de Laponie',
    'Berger Hollandais' => 'Berger Hollandais',
    'Berger Islandais' => 'Berger Islandais',
    'Bouvier de l\'Entlebuch' => 'Bouvier de l\'Entlebuch',
    'Bouvier des Ardennes' => 'Bouvier des Ardennes',
    'Bouvier des Flandres' => 'Bouvier des Flandres',
    'Boxer' => 'Boxer',
    'Autre' => 'Autre');

    echo '<div id="divFields">';    
    echo '<label for="chien" class="breed">Race du chien: 
    </label>';
    echo '<input id="chien" type="text" list="chiendata">';
    echo '<datalist id="chiendata" name="chiendata" >';
    echo '<label for="adresse">ou sélectionner dans la 
    liste</label>';
    echo '<select name="adresse" class="selected" id="adresse" 
    onChange="AjoutOptionAuSelect(this)"  style="width: -webkit- 
    fill-available;" size="1">';
    foreach($list as $p => $row){
    echo "<option  value='".$p."'>" . $row ."</option>" ; 
    }
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</datalist>';
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<label for="name" class="breed">Si autre préciser : 
    </label>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div>';
    echo '<input type="text" name="dog">';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

  }

    add_shortcode ('dog_api', 'dog_func');



    function dog_shortcode(){
        echo '<input type="button" class="add" value="Ajouter un chien" id="test" onClick="addField();">';

}
add_shortcode( 'dog_breed' , 'dog_shortcode');





function addField() {
     var field = "<input type='text' name='' value=''/>";
     document.getElementById('divFields').innerHtml += field;
     console.log('test');
}
```

I explain I must create a form to add dogs for races, so I try to add with a button my select as much as needed to add the breed of 2 dogs, 3, 5 any matter,
My select is a shortcode to insert it in Elementor that the client wanted

Answer (score 2):

In order to append html within a div.

```
function addField() {
     var field = "<input type='text' name='' value=''/>";
     // WITH JQuery
     $("#divFields").append(field);          
     // WITH JS
     document.getElementById('divFields').appendChild(field ); 
}
```

Life is a lot easier with jQuery, you may use [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: It's not HTML it's HTML echo is it possible to still use your technique, however I do not know at all jQuery is it possible to help me?

Comment: ` var field ='<?=$php_field_value?>'; ` this should work fine.

Comment: I tested :
function addField() {
    var field = '<?= $atts ?>';
    document.getElementById('divFields').appendChild(field); 
console.log('test');
}

Comment: and (function ($){
$('#divFields').click(function(){
    console.log('coucou1');
    var field = "<input type='text' name='' value=''/>";
  console.log('coucou2');
    $("#div").append(field);     
    console.log('coucou3');    
  
})

})(jQuery)

Comment: none work for the first I get an error : Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.
    at addField (dog.js?ver=1.0.0:4)
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)

Comment: and for the second no error but nothing is displayed